# Is it possible to I create LabelTemplates for Html.Label and Html.LabelFor() in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For reasons that are questionable but practical, I'd like to create LabelTemplate defaults, just like EditorTemplates or DisplayTemplates.

So instead of this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.PropertyName, "Property Name")
```

or instead of this(the better way to do it in a View Model):

```
[DisplayName("Property Name")]
public string PropertyName{ get; set; }
```

**I want this:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.PropertyName)
```

With this (in a folder like this: /Views/Shared/LabelTemplates)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.String>" %>
//Display logic here
```

Can you help a coder out?

Comment: How is this different from `DisplayTemplates`?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own custom html helper.

http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/

Comment: Decent answer, only had to do an additional search and replace all, thank you!

Here is my implementation:

        `public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor2<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) where TModel : class
        {
            var prop = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

            var sp = AddSpaces(prop);
            var lb = "<label for='" + prop + "'>" + sp + "</label>";
            return new MvcHtmlString(lb);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you can use to convert your property names:

```
Regex.Replace("PropertyName", "[a-z][A-Z]", m => m.Value[0] + " " + m.Value[1]);
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted answer in the right tab of your browser?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov it actually looked to me like they understood how to create the template but were just looking for how to split the `PropertyName`.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>I know this isn't strictly an answer to your question, but since I still want to suggest a plan of action, I'll post it like this rather than in a comment.</sup>

---

**Are you sure you want this?**

If you manage to do this, you will set the *label* of a field to some value based on its *type*. This might seem tempting at first glance - you could possibly save yourself some key strokes every here and there.

But what happens if you e.g. have a type `Address` containing some properties for street name, number, zip code etc, and then want the user to fill in the home address and the work address in the same form - how would you label them differently and still use the same type? And even worse - do you *really* want the same label on all your strings? In order to avoid these two scenarios, you'll need to resort to `Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PropertyName, "TemplateName")` anyway, which means you'll be in just as sorry a situation as you already are. Furthermore, you'll have at least two places you have to look to find the correct display logic for your label, rather than just one.

Remember that there is no absolute requirement to use the `LabelFor()` helper - you can just as well just roll your own extension method on `HtmlHelper`, or even ignore them and output plane HTML:

```
<label for="Person_HomeAddress">Home address</label> <!-- the ID might be wrong -->
<%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.HomeAddress) %>
```

Since the `EditorFor()` outputs an ID matched to the name of the model and property names, you'll be fine.