# What is the correct way to overrride the Html.DisplayFor<> helper for a custom object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

If I have an object and view as:

```
public MyCustomerObject
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Label {get;set;}
    Public string Value {get;set;}
}

@model IEnumerable<MyCustomObject>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => item)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item)
}
```

What is the correct way to override the `LabelFor<>` and `DisplayFor<>` extensions to allow me to deal with `MyCustomObject` in a way other than the default, without affecting it's ability to deal with other types as it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a folder called `DisplayTemplates` in your view folder. Create a view called `MyCustomObject.cshtml` with `MyCustomObject` as model. Now MVC will use this view when you use `DisplayFor`. The same counts for `EditorFor`, the name of the folder should be `EditorTemplates` then.

`LabelFor`, however, has no template options.

See [this blogpost](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx) by Scott Hanselman for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this through code without creating views?

Comment: @JohnFreebs Not that I know. Why would you want that? Perhaps you can elaborate what you want?

Comment: You may have a point, doing it in code would simply make the output harder to maintain by a non coder. Is my only option for the Label to then use `@Html.Label(item.Id, item.Label)` to directly tell it what values to use since you say there is no templating for it?

Comment: @JohnFreebs There is indeed no such thing as `LabelTemplates`. You could create an `HtmlHelper` which returns a label for your specific model property. Also: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900319/is-it-possible-to-i-create-labeltemplates-for-html-label-and-html-labelfor-in) question.

Comment: I think then that I can sum up my original intention as having the `DisplayFor<>` and `LabelFor<>` be able to handle my custom types in a bespoke way without the person writing the views needing to know to use a different `Label` helper when outputting labels for that type.

Comment: @JohnFreebs you can also create 2 different ViewModels. One for the label and one for the value. Then you can use `DisplayFor` on both properties with different `DisplayTemplates`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be able to solve my requirement using your help.